# Umbraco - Read only Content Picker - I know weird, but this is what I need

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Currently I have a node picker on a document type.

I'm using the Umbraco event methods to manage its value. This is working perfectly.

However,

I want to be able to display the value preferably just as a string like this:

Home > About > Contact

Making it a read only value, so the user can see it but can not change it. (That will be done by the Umbraco Events)

Can anyone give me any pointers of how I can do this?

Comment: Running Umbraco 7 by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this so I thought I would answer the question for others.

Instead of using a content picker, I used a label that will store string that looks something like this:

> "[1072] : Home >> Our company"

The Umbraco events in my application create the string when saving and when reading the code parse's the int within the []

Works really well. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a quick custom property editor if you are comfortable working with Angular JS. I would create the property editor so that it stores the node id and renders breadcrumbs to the node. I would use the entityResource to query umbraco for the data on your node. You can even build your own API controller if you want to and query that.

Here's some documentation that I think will really come in handy:

- [Documentation on creating custom property editors](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/)
- [Documentation on querying umbraco via Angular JS in the backoffice](https://our.umbraco.org/apidocs/ui/#/api/umbraco.resources.entityResource)

Comment: This solution is good, but a lot more than I really need, but thanks!